# Issue with R Animation: missing axis labels and tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, axis, gganimate

I've just begun to explore animations using ggplot2 and gganimate, and in multiple use cases I'm finding that elements like legends and axis labels are being omitted from the final animation. For example, if I run the following code...

```
anim <- ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Species), size=2) 

anim
```

...the output contains all of the expected formatting elements like axis labeling and legend:

[axis labeling and legend intact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJfP3.png)

However, if I continue to add animation elements with the below code, the output omits the axis labeling and legend.

```
anim <- ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Species), size=2) + 
  transition_states(Species,transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) 

anim+enter_fade()+exit_disappear()
```

[missing axis labels and legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQTE.png)

I expected the animated plot to mirror my the ggplot output prior to adding animation effects. I tried adding scale_x_continuous at the very end but this did not yield the desired effect.

Curious if I've omitted a key argument here. Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. How are you viewing the animation? Does the problem persist when saving to file?

Comment: I'm using RStudio. Also tried anim_save to save as a .gif but issue still persists.

Comment: Worked fine for me too. Maybe you could share more about what package versions (gganimate, ggplot2) and what specific code you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. ggplot2 version is 3.4.4.9000, gganimate is 1.0.8.9000. I'm using the second code chunk above. Let me know if I can be more specific.

Comment: Also I checked to ensure my RStudio is up to date.  Version 2023.09.1+494. I have gifski (1.12.0-2) installed and loaded.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to get the code to run properly on Posit Cloud. Are there any ideas on what may be causing an issue when I run animation code locally? I'd like to avoid having to subscribe to a cloud service as a permanent workaround. Note all packages appear to be up to date.

Comment: What OS are you on? What graphics device are you using and what code to save?

Comment: I'm on macOS 11.4. Apple M1 chip with 7-core GPU.  Will try updating OS and see if that yields a fix.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "what code to save"? I'm assuming you mean something other than what is posted above. Appreciate your willingness to help!

Comment: Updated to OS macOS 14.1.2 but still experiencing original issue

Comment: Try installing the CRAN versions instead of the github development versions you have now. Otherwise I am at a loss.

Comment: Success!  Re-installed the gganimate and ggplot2 through CRAN (I thought that was the original source of those packages but perhaps not after all). Tried a couple of other animation use cases and those worked too. Thanks so much!